# Need method to convert Excel to Tab Delimited txt file in Unicode encoding

Tags: excel, unicode, encoding

I have some excel files containing some French characters, for example "Jean-Léon Gérôme"
when I convert the excel file to tab delimited txt file, the default encoding is ANSI and the French characters became Gibberish, so I need a method that can convert the excel file to tab delimited file and at the same time in Unicode encoding.

(I know excel can directly export to Unicode text, but that is not what I need, I need the file in **tab delimited txt** and in **Unicode** encoding)

Please help. thanks a lot!

Comment: Unicode isn't an encoding, although Microsoft typically calls UTF-16 "Unicode".  Do you mean UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoding?  An editor such as Notepad++ can convert from ANSI to UTF-8/16 if there are not too many files; otherwise, a scripting language such as Python can mass convert files.  Which do you need?

Comment: I have tried to covnert the txt file to UTF-8 but the gibberish still exists, so I think I need to convert it into UTF-16 and try my luck, but I didn't find a UTF-16 option in Notepad++ or Sublime Text Editor, how can I convert the file to UTF-16?

Comment: In Notepad++, "Convert to UCS-2 Little-Endian" is a subset (or misnamed) UTF-16.  If you use UTF-8, and are opening the result in Excel again, Excel requires "Convert to UTF-8 with BOM".  It shouldn't be gibberish if you open a file saved as ANSI in Notepad++.  You may need to describe exactly how you are saving and viewing your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply saving an Excel file as "Unicode text" saved the file tab-delimited in UTF-16.  Here is the result opened in Notepad++.  Note that the encoding is "UCS-2 Little Endian" which is a subset of UTF-16.  It only supports characters up to Unicode 65535 (`U+FFFF`), but that includes French characters so no worries:

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot Mark. I need the final encoding in Western (Windows 1252),so based on your method, I got a tab-delimited file in UTF-16, then I use Sublime Text → File → Save with Encoding →  Western (Windows 1252) and I get the file I want. Headache removed!  : )